# How to parse with rapidjson from std::string?

Tags: c++, rapidjson

How to parse with rapidjson from std::string ?
I am trying like (json string is valid, I checked on [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com))

```
Document document;
char * writable = new char[contentString.size() + 1];
std::copy(contentString.begin(), contentString.end(), writable);
writable[contentString.size()] = '\0'; // don't forget the terminating 0
std::cout<<writable<<"\n";
if (document.Parse<0>(writable).HasParseError())
    return 1;
```

**contentString** is my **json std::string**, but when I start I always get error ( **return 1**).
I tried also without size()+1 and '\0' but nothing (desperate measure programming).
Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 7):

Try this for parse std:: string

```
std::string str = "{ \"hello\" : \"world\" }";
copiedDocument.Parse<0>(str.c_str());
```

Answer (score 5):

if contentString is std::string, just try

```
document.Parse<0>(contentString.c_str()).HasParseError()
```

if contentString is char *, just try

```
document.Parse<0>(contentString).HasParseError()
```

and you'd better post your original code snippet

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried

```
if (document.Parse<0>(contentString.c_str()).HasParseError())
    return 1;
```

?

Because, from the documentation, I fail to see why you want anything "writable"...

Comment: I have tried that way at first, but error. Then I have started to change

Comment: In that case, please always post the obvious code, not the complicated version. And show us the contentString, please.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me there is an error with the string you send json,
You are using it correctly, I suggest you try sending it:

```
const char json[] = "{ \"hello\" : \"world\" }";
```

And see if it works, if so obviously it's a buffer problem.. you can continue from there I am sure